# Angular & TailwindCSS - Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu, dropdown, tailwind-css

Apologies if this has been answered before, but I have been searching for a couple of days to find an answer and I have not come across a solution that makes sense for my setup (perhaps my setup is wrong, let find out).

I would like to create a dropdown menu using Angular with Tailwind CSS, My component html is as follows:

```
// recipe-details.component.html
<div>
  <div *ngIf="selectedRecipe;else noRecipe">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
      <h3 class="text-title">{{ selectedRecipe.name }}</h3>

      <!-- The dropdown menu -->
      <div class="relative">

        <!-- The dropdown button -->
        <a href="#" class="bg-green-500 px-3 py-2 rounded-md shadow font-bold text-white flex items-center" appDropdown>Manage recipe
          <svg class="w-5 h-5 ml-2" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"></path>
          </svg></a>

          <!-- Dropdown list of links -->
          <div class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 w-full rounded mt-2 shadow-lg border-gray-800">
            <div class="bg-white py-2">
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 font-bold text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100">Edit Recipe</a>
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 font-bold text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100">Delete Recipe</a>
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <p>{{ selectedRecipe.description }}</p>
  </div>

  <ng-template #noRecipe>
    <div class="">
      <div class="text-title ">Choose a recipe</div>
      <p>Please choose a recipe from the recipe list.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

For the menu button I have created a directive with selector *appDropdown*:

```
//dropdown.directive.ts
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  @Output() isMenuOpen = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  isOpen: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click') toggleMenu() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    this.isMenuOpen.emit(this.isOpen);
    console.log(`Menu status changed. Menu is now ${this.isOpen ? 'Open' : 'Closed'}`)
  }

}
```

If my way of thinking so far makes sense, does it make further sense to handle the EventEmitter in another directive and place it on the *dropdown list of links div*. The directive would use a HostBinding to apply css to set the opacity of the div between `opacity-0` and `opacity-100` whether `isOpen` is **true** or **false**?

If this approach works, I am not sure how I would listen for the Event from the first directive within the second directive.

If I am completely off the mark, does anyone have a solution that would help me understand the workflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess writing my question down this way helped me come up with a solution. If anyone has a way to improve my code, feel free to post other ways it can be done :)

My solution:

```
//recipe-detail.component.html
<div>
  <div *ngIf="selectedRecipe;else noRecipe">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
      <h3 class="text-title">{{ selectedRecipe.name }}</h3>
      <div class="relative">
        <a href="#" class="bg-green-500 px-3 py-2 rounded-md shadow font-bold text-white flex items-center" (isMenuOpen)=toggleVisible($event) appDropdown>Manage recipe
          <svg class="w-5 h-5 ml-2" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7"></path>
          </svg></a>
          <div class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 w-full rounded mt-2 shadow-lg border-gray-800" [ngClass]="visibilityClasses">
            <div class="bg-white py-2">
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 font-bold text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100">Edit Recipe</a>
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 font-bold text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100">Delete Recipe</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>{{ selectedRecipe.description }}</p>
  </div>

  <ng-template #noRecipe>
    <div class="">
      <div class="text-title ">Choose a recipe</div>
      <p>Please choose a recipe from the recipe list.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

```
//recipe-detail.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from 'src/app/models/models.i';
import { RecipeService } from '../../../services/recipes/recipe.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-detail',
  templateUrl: './recipe-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-detail.component.scss']
})
export class RecipeDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedRecipe: Recipe;
  visibilityClasses: {};
  private isVisible: boolean = false;

  constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.recipeService.currentRecipe.subscribe(recipe => this.selectedRecipe = recipe
    );
    this.setVisibilityClasses();
  }

  toggleVisible(isVisible: boolean): void {
    console.log(`is the menu open: ${isVisible ? 'Yes' : 'No'}`)
    this.isVisible = isVisible;
    this.setVisibilityClasses();
  }

  private setVisibilityClasses(): void {
    this.visibilityClasses = {
      'opacity-0': !this.isVisible,
      'opacity-100': this.isVisible
    };
  }
}
```

```
//dropdown.directive.ts
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  @Output() isMenuOpen = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  isOpen: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click') toggleMenu() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    this.isMenuOpen.emit(this.isOpen);
    console.log(`Menu status changed. Menu is now ${this.isOpen ? 'Open' : 'Closed'}`)
  }
}
```